# Cannot load file in folder outside the css folder

Tags: html, css

I cannot load image as a background, my image located at

```
img/my_images.jpg
```

and this is my css code look like

```
.background-content
    {
    background-image: url(img/my_images.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    }
```

the css file is located at

```
css/my_style.css
```

but everytime I move the image into the same folder as css, it does load the image perfectly.
is it impossible to load image from outside folder of css

thanks for the help.

sincerely, gema.

Comment: thankss, i solved this problem my self, it needs to be started with "/" first if you wanna go to root folder then to another folder. Thanks stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but you probably just need to use the "up one level" syntax:

```
background-image: url(../img/my_images.jpg);
```

This gets you up into the parent folder of /css/, and then back down into /img/.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
background-image: url(img/my_images.jpg);
```

to this

```
background-image: url(../img/my_images.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

The image loads relative to where the css is located. So your image would have to be in

```
  css/img/my_images.jpg
```

I'm guessing you want

```
  background-image: url(../img/my_images.jpg)
```

I prefer to do everything from the root

```
  background-image: url(/img/my_images.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcus is correct you likely need to go back a directory with ../images/you pic.jpg